# Green function for particular boundary condition

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, greens-functions

> Find the Green function for the Poisson equation *between* two infinitely long concentric cylinders of radii $r_1$ and $r_2$ with the boundary condition $u\left(r_1,\theta\right)=u\left(r_2,\theta+\pi/4\right)=\sin 4\theta$. Let $r_1 \lt r_2$ (almost) without loss of generality. What happens in the following limits?
>
> (i) $r_1 \to 0$
>
> (ii) $r_2 \to \infty$
>
> (iii) $r_1 \to 0$ and $r_2 \to \infty$
>
> (iv) $r_2 \to r_1 +\epsilon$ with $\epsilon/r_1 \ll 1$

I need to find the Green function for this boundary condition but I could not understand one thing, i.e. when we write equation for the Green function it always gives a solution similar to that of potential for a point charge. Then how could I impose this boundary condition on that solution. Also, if I give solution in terms of Legendre polynomials, then I could not figure out mathematically how different regions (i.e $r \gt r'$ and $r \lt r'$) have different solutions.

P.S. I may not be able to articulate myself clearly as I am completely confused. Please feel free to point out if I have missed something.

Comment: If you can solve the equation with these boundary conditions, you can just as well find the green's function with these bc. But you may need to look up math books for technical details.